# Unable to mock Model::where() and prevent test from querying database

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

In my controller I'm using `MyModel::where(...)` which is calling the database during one of my tests.  I thought that I'd be able to overload it with the following but it's still querying the database.  What can I do to be sure my test is still requiring that `::where` is called but returns a mocked model so I can resume testing the rest of this controller method?

```
MyModel::shouldReceive('where')
  ->once()
  ->with('param1', 'param2')
  ->andReturn($mockedModel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand why you can't mock the `where` method. That's because the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` (Eloquent is its alias) doesn't have a `where` method explicitly declared. This method is called through the magic methods `__callStatic` and `__call` and is, in fact, a method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` ([sources](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2825-L2842)).

Then, you have several options :

1. You can accept to call your database in your tests and just define a real context before your assertions. Your tests will be less unitary but we can deal with that in most of the cases.
2. @michaelcurry solution is a good one. You can build your own abstraction layer with query scopes or other architecture (injecting the query builder by yourself in the model for example) to produce a more testable code.
3. [never tried] You can mock directly the `DB` facade to completely bypass the database. You will need a good understanding of the Laravel core but it could be a good way to write "pure" unit tests.

Anyway, don't hesitate to dive into the Laravel source code. The code is clear and there are just few classes really important. That's essential to really exploit the power of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes and create a new function that just returns the data you want.

If you have not read it "Laravel: From Apprentice To Artisan" I would suggest it.  Will help you understand how all of this is structured.

Comment: Great suggestion for this scenario... but it still seems to be hitting the database.